# How to see what symbols are hosted on a Symbol Server?

Tags: nuget, symbols, pdb-files, nuget-server

I would like to inspect what symbols are available on a symbol server. I expect that a symbol server hosts more or less a collection of `.pdb` files for various applications.

Tools like Visual Studio or WinDbg must know how to communicate with symbol servers hosted online. Here are URLs of some symbol servers found in Google, the first two are probably the default ones used by Visual Studio 2022:

- https://symbols.nuget.org/download/symbols
- https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
- http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
- https://nuget.smbsrc.net/

I expect that all of them follow some common standard, but when opened in a browser, none of them seems to offer a GUI or even a hint how to interact with them.

Is there some sort of standard REST API or a documented protocol that would allow seeing what's hosted on a symbol server?

Comment: I'm searching the same thing, found this: https://gist.github.com/Barakat/e20ec993748c6ab382d727f08eaa523e, but not tried.

Comment: The previous snipped doesn't seem to work anymore. I've forked it and updated the format https://gist.github.com/0blu/ee3663ed65e8a279873b33c9448376dc